# Stub methods of @Mock before injection by @InjectMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Constructor of my class gets a property from an injected object and saves a transformed result into final var.

For testing, method of injected mock should be stubbed before constructor injection. However, it seems that `@InjectMocks` performs injections before `@BeforeEach` so methods of injected mock are not stubbed and return null and test fails to start.

Is it possible to use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` in such cases?

```java
class A {
    String c;

    A(B b) {
        c = requireNonNull(b.getC())
    }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ATest {
    @Mock B b;
    @InjectMocks A a;

    @BeforeEach void setUp() {
        when(b.getC()).thenReturn("");
    }

    @Test void test() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not aware there are ways that can stub on a mock before `@InjectMocks` inject it to another object.

But you can make your life easier if you create `A` and inject its dependencies manually rather than using `@InjectMocks` :

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ATest {

    @Mock B b;
    A a;

    @BeforeEach 
    void setUp() {
        when(b.getC()).thenReturn("");
        a = new A(b);
    }

    @Test void test() {

    }
}
```

And the test codes become cleaner and easier to understand IMO.